# Why is my .NET SQL command with parameters not updating all the fields?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there something wrong with my sql statement? because only the Client_Name is being updated and the rest stays the same.

I already checked if all the textbox and combobox are not null and is different from the original data

```
sql = "UPDATE Client_Info SET Client_Name= @a, Gender= @b, Age= @c, Birthdate= @d, Address= @e, Email_Address= @f, Contact_Number= @h WHERE Client_Name='" & TextBox8.Text & "'"
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@a", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox18.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@b", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox8.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@c", OleDb.OleDbType.BigInt).Value = TextBox17.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@d", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = ComboBox7.Text & " " & ComboBox6.Text & ", " & ComboBox5.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@e", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox16.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@f", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox15.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@h", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox14.Text

        sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Why use parameters for all of those values but pass the client name by adding strings?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Try executing *the same* SQL directly, by replacing all parameters with respective value. You will see the problem. And read and understand why Slaks did that.

Comment: Your problem is that for non-string data types you need to convert text to the expected type and also, add a parameter to WHERE

Comment: If the data types were wrong, there would be an error and nothing would update.   Maybe he's updating/looking-in different databases.

Comment: @SteveWellens why leave data type conversion to implicit db conversion?

Comment: ANother thing - stop using OleDb. Use `SqlClient`

Comment: @T.S. - I didn't say that.   Please re-read my comment so I don't have to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@c", OleDb.OleDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.Int64(TextBox17.Text)

sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@d", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.DateTime(ComboBox7.Text & "/" & ComboBox6.Text & "/" & ComboBox5.Text)
```

Comment: for `BigInt` you better convert using `Convert.ToInt64`